# Grafana stacking multiple bars in bar chart by specific column

Tags: grafana

I have these bars with the query within the picture.
[image]

```
SELECT 
  area, 
  SUM(case when report_date = '2022-04-18' then volume else 0 end )  AS "22-04-18 Volume",
  SUM(case when report_date = '2022-04-25' then volume else 0 end ) AS "22-04-25 Volume",
  SUM(case when report_date = '2022-04-18' then sales else 0 end )  AS "22-04-18 Sales",
  SUM(case when report_date = '2022-04-25' then sales else 0 end ) AS "22-04-25 Sales"
FROM test
WHERE (report_date = '2022-04-18' 
   OR report_date = '2022-04-25')
GROUP BY area
```

I want to stack the bars stacked on each other volume from one week + volume from other week, sales from one week + sales from other week by area but I get this:
[image]

Is there a way to accomplish this? Table below:

[image: ![image|630x500](upload://o6lPgoUO7lux0qPydYa6rPGwe6c.png)]